# Jquery Inputmask Latitude & Longitude Validation and Masking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, latitude-longitude, masking, jquery-inputmask

I am using [InputMask](https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/) Jquery library for Latitude & Longitude Masking, anyone has idea how to do this using the library.

Masking should return `true` on following values:

90.366565665
-90.365333336
+90.365333336
180.36663663
-180.36633666
+180.36633666

Thanks,
Kaleem

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#Longitude").inputmask({
    mask: "E|W99[9].999",
    definitions: {
        "E": {
            validator: "[eE]",
            cardinality: 1,
            casing: "upper"
        },
        "W": {
            validator: "[wW]",
            cardinality: 1,
            casing: "upper"
        }
    }
});
```

Ref: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues/770

Answer (score 0):

**__°__'__"_**

your input text field looks like above

```
if (type === 'lt') {
  $('input#' + id).inputmask({
    mask: '89°M9\'S9"D',
    definitions: {
      D: {
        validator: '[eE|wW]',
        cardinality: 1,
        casing: 'upper'
      },
      M: {
        validator: '[0-5]',
        cardinality: 1
      },
      S: {
        validator: '[0-5]',
        cardinality: 1
      },
      8: {
        validator: '[0-8]',
        cardinality: 1
      }
    }
  });
} else if (type === 'lg') {
  $('input#' + id).inputmask({
    mask: ['99°M9\'S9"D', '[1]79°M9\'S9"D'],
    definitions: {
      D: {
        validator: '[nN|sS]',
        cardinality: 1,
        casing: 'upper'
      },
      M: {
        validator: '[0-5]',
        cardinality: 1
      },
      S: {
        validator: '[0-5]',
        cardinality: 1
      },
      7: {
        validator: '[0-7]',
        cardinality: 1
      }
    }
  });
}
```